# Struggle with Binary Substraction with using two's complement

Tags: math, architecture, binary

I have to solve a  **binary substraction** of the following exercise:

**-6 + 4.5**

We know that -6 + 4.5 = 4.5 - 6;

As we know, **to perform the subtraction of signed numbers (M – N)  we should find the 2’s complement of the N , and add it to M.**

4.5 = 0100.1
6 = 0110; 2's complement of 6 is 1010

Now addition:

0100.1 + 1010 = 1110.1

The rule says, if the summation does not produce an end carry,
the leftmost bit is the sign bit.

1110.1 = -6.5
But the result should be -1.5

The question is: Where is my mistake?

Comment: Since your value is negative, you have to take the 2's complement to get the magnitude of the negative value. The 2's complement of `1110.1` is `0001.1` or 1.5.

Comment: Isn't it 0010.1 which is 2.5?

Comment: Because 1110.1 -> 0001.1 +1 -> 0010.1

Comment: `1110.1` -> `0001.0 + 0000.1` -> `0001.1`. If the binary point is causing you confusion, multiply the number by two, take the 2's complement, and then divide two to undo the multiplication.

Comment: \*"divide **by** two"